# Storybook + Font Files

Tags: javascript, webpack, storybook

I can't seem to get Storybook's webpack to compile my CSS. It throws up on the font files and tells me I may need a loader, but I've added one to the `webpack.config.js` file it's using.

Here is my `webpack.config.js`:

```
const resolve = require('path').resolve;

module.exports = {
  module: {
    loaders: [
      {
        test: /\.css$/,
        loaders: ['style', 'css', 'postcss?modules'],
        include: resolve(__dirname, '../')
      },
      {
        test: /\.(png|woff|woff2|eot|ttf|svg)$/,
        loaders: ['file'],
        include: resolve(__dirname, '../')
      }
    ]
  }
};
```

I have the loader and it sees it, but it still gives me errors like this:

```
ERROR in ./~/font-awesome/fonts/fontawesome-webfont.svg?v=4.7.0
Module parse failed: /home/dcpdev/projects/my-project/node_modules/font-awesome/fonts/fontawesome-webfont.svg?v=4.7.0 Unexpected token (1:0)
You may need an appropriate loader to handle this file type.
SyntaxError: Unexpected token (1:0)
    at Parser.pp$4.raise (/home/dcpdev/projects/my-project/node_modules/webpack/node_modules/acorn/dist/acorn.js:2221:15)
    at Parser.pp.unexpected (/home/dcpdev/projects/my-project/node_modules/webpack/node_modules/acorn/dist/acorn.js:603:10)
    at Parser.pp$3.parseExprAtom (/home/dcpdev/projects/my-project/node_modules/webpack/node_modules/acorn/dist/acorn.js:1822:12)
    <snip>
```

I get one of those errors for each extension (eot, woff, woff2, ttf, svg).

I know it's reading that `webpack.config.js` file, because if I do something like change to a nonsensical loader name (like `cake`), I get an error from it.

Also, the file is in a `storybook` directory off the root of my project, so `resolve(__dirname, '../')` should put it at the root of my project as well.

What am I missing?

Comment: this in my opinion is one of the fundamental flaws with webpack, it promises to add all this incredible functionality but it takes away basic things like being able to add font to a project unless you specifically tell it to expect it. There's so much configuration that should come as default.

Answer (score 11):

3 months late, but did you manage to get this working?

I was struggling with the same problem, and adding the following code to the `webpack.config.js` seems to have worked:

```
{
    test: /\.(png|woff|woff2|eot|ttf|svg)$/,
    loaders: ['file-loader'],
    include: path.resolve(__dirname, '../')
}
```

Hopefully that may help someone else facing a similar problem.

Comment: Awesome!! It helped =) I'm upvoting this answer.

Comment: I had something very similar to the above, but without the `png` and `svg` in the regex. Adding the `svg` solved it for me (font-awesome). Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Works for me:

```
config.resolve.roots = [path.resolve(__dirname, '../public')];
```

No additional configuration was required actually. Storybook just unable to find the context.